# Application and Firmware Separation in Cortex M4

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I'm busy with a massive project where I need write software for a control system for an automotive vehicle. Here's what I am using:

1. I'm using an STM32F4 for the micro
2. I am writing the Application (Control app) in Matlab Simulink. I then generate Cortex M4 optimised code from Matlab which I simply Include in my Keil uVision Project. (Works like a charm)
3. I manually write software for the driver layer and to interface to the Hardware abstraction Layer.

I would like to maintain separation between my Simulink Generated Code and my 'firmware' hand written code. Essentially, I want to be able to change the firmware without affecting my control application.

I would like to use a configuration file to map the variables that Matlab Simulink generates with my Hardware Registers (for GPIO, for instance). I would like to do this via a configuration file (e.g. via an xml file).

Has anyone ever done something like this and is it even possible. I'm looking for an elegant solution that does not consume a lot of RAM.

Thanks so much!

PS: Is it possible to declare variables in your code based on variables names that are stored in say an .xml or .txt file.

So if in the .txt file I have "Pressure_Sensor = 0", is it possible, perhaps using a Macro Definition, to declare a variable in the code: Pressure_Sensor = 0;

Comment: Can you communicate via a software interrupt?

Comment: Hi Martin. Yes Software Interrupts work just fine. Please see the comments below for more clarification about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include variables into your `c` project build from syntax in another type of file whether it be .xml or .txt files there's a couple ways to do it. If you are going to be keeping variables in `c` compatible declaration style like:

```
int Pressure_Sensor = 0;
```

and no other invalid semantics will be in that file you can always just include that file into one of your compilation units. The extensions of the file do not matter. The `#include` directive literally just inserts that file into place.

If you are going to be doing something along the lines of a non `c` compatible language such as XML, a standard way to generate and include those variables into your build is to have a script that runs are a pre-build action that parses that .xml file and then generates a `c` compatible include file that you include into one of your compilation units. One of the most common things to use this for that you could find many examples of is for generating version/build info into the build.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers.  The thing is,  I would like to do the variable mapping post compilation during run time... I know of it sounds impossible bit I'm writing the code for an automotive vehicle and it really helps not to recompile application  because the IO mapping has changed. If there's an easier way I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: To elaborate further, let's say I control a contactor K1 which is mapped to a particular pin on my ic. If for whatever reason during the field we have to rewire that contactor and then remap it to another pin,  would it be possible via a configuration file to also remap the variable K1 to the new hardware pin / register.

Comment: To do something like that you would either have to have memory access to the device and the variable stored in a known location so that you could change it from an external system. The device could also read/parse this configuration file when it receives a specific signal, at power up, etc. That would require the device to somehow have access to this file. About the only other thing I can think of is sending configuration messages to the device over whatever interface you choose of and then that device changes its configuration based on the message. All will be very implementation specific.

Comment: "About the only other thing I can think of is sending configuration messages to the device over whatever interface you choose of and then that device changes its configuration based on the message" - This.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Simplified Problem Statement is: 
You want to modify a CPU port register through your code, but you don't know the address of that port register(Port address may change externally).

Solution is:
I)In your code:

Let your program assume that the address of the port register is at at fix location say 0x1000.
Someone/something  will letter put address of port register at 0x1000(Your program don't care how) 
So to change pin K1 you have to change value of address present at 0x1000.
But Wait ,
You want to only change a single port pin and you don't know which so,
Assume pin bit pattern is at 0x1004

To make pin ON write:
Value of the address present at 0x1000 |= Value at 0x1002
To make pin OFF write:
Value of the address present at 0x1000 &= ~Value at 0x1002

Most Imp:
Reserve these locations in your program somehow so that compiler dont write code there.

II)Outside the code:
 Assumptions for explanation: Port1 address : 0xF000
                              Port2 address : 0xF001 
 Now have a Excel macro or something to do following:
 Suppose you wants port2's  8th pin for contactor K1 then that macro should generate a simple text file as: "F00180".
 Now use bin2hex or bin2mot (based) on your compilers output format and convert this notepad file into .hex or .mot(S-record) format.
 You have to specify address location as 0x1000 as one of the input to these utilities.

Now remove header ,footer lines from generated .hex file and merge remaining data to your program.hex file.

You are done here,burn the .hex file into target by suitable flash programmer.